# v-show based on select option data attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Used HTML and VueJS to show div if value ="two". it works fine.

Now, we need to v-show div elements based on data attribute - data-is-valid. If data-is-valid=true, show div element.

Tried with different method as of i know. I can able to get this functionality only with select option. Not with data attribute.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    selectedOption: ''
  },
  methods: {
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="topic">Topic</label>
        <div class="custom-chosen-wrapper" :class="{'text-error': errors.has('nyp-contact-topic')}">
            <select class="select-topic" v-validate="'required'" v-model="selectedOption" v-on:change="onChangeSelectedTopic">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="One" data-is-valid="false">One</option>
                <option value="Two" data-is-valid="true">Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" v-show="selectedOption == 'true'" v-cloak="v-cloak">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <div class="custom-chosen-wrapper">
            <select class="chosen-select select-picker select-picker-link" name="personal-salutation" v-validate="selectedOption === 'true' ? 'required' : ''" tabindex="-98">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select salutation</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
                <option value="Madam">Madam</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Where you appended the `data` attribute and how you tried to access the data.

Comment: Let's figure out, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments and session @Syed

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer or you solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    select(v-model="selectedOption" v-on:change="onChangeSelectedTopic")
      option(value="") Select
      option(value="One" data-is-valid="false") One
      option(value="Two" data-is-valid="true") Two
    div(v-show="selectDataValidate")
      // show or hide content
<template>
```

declare this in you `data`:

```
data: {
  selectedOption: '',
  selectDataValidate: false
}
```

As you have mentioned in our skype call that you are using `jQuery` so here is the solution:

```
methods: {
  onChangeSelectedTopic: (e) => {
    if($(e).find(':selected').attr('data-is-valid') == 'true'){
      instance.selectDataValidate = true;
    }  else {
      instance.selectDataValidate = false;
    }  
  }
},
```